# How do I get the command line arguments in Go without the "flags" package?

Tags: command-line, go

I'm trying to write a GNU-style command-line parser for Go, since the `flags` package doesn't handle all these yet:

```
program -aAtGc --long-option-1 argument-to-1 --long-option-2 -- real-argument
```

Obviously, I don't want to use the `flags` package, since I'm trying to replace it. Is there any other way to get to the command line?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Nevermind.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", len(args))

    for i := 0; i<len(args); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", args[i])
    }
}
```

The documentation is quite incomplete, though.

Comment: I'm looking for an implementation of this,  just wondering if you finisned it/opensourced the code?

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I don't know if this is relevant or not. But other may find it useful.
There are two ways to run this.
1) go build prog.go
./prog hello world slappa
2) go run prog.go hello world slappa

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of os.Args is the name of the go file, so to get only the command line arguments, you should do something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]

    for i := 0; i<len(args); i++ {
        fmt.Println(args[i])
    }
}
```